# Is this characterization of a curve on a surface using lines of curvature correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

Let $\alpha$ be a curve on a surface with Gaussian curvature $K=-1$ and let $N$ be the surface normal along $\alpha$. Assume that
\begin{equation}
\langle\alpha'(t),N(t)\rangle=0\quad\text{and}\quad\langle\alpha'(t),N'(t)\rangle\neq 0
\end{equation}
for all $t$. I came across a document where the author says that if this holds then

> $\alpha'(t)$ and $N'(t)$ are everywhere or nowhere parallel, i.e., $\alpha$ is everywhere or nowhere tangent to a principal direction.

I don't seem to know how to use the two given assumptions to prove that $\alpha'(t)$ and $N'(t)$ are everywhere or nowhere parallel, nor that $\alpha$ is everywhere or nowhere tangent to a principal direction. Actually, it is not clear to me why these two conclusions are equivalent: if for each $t$ we have that $\alpha$ is tangent to a principal direction, then $\alpha$ is a line of curvature. This means, using Rodrigues' curvature formula, that $N'(t)+k_i(t)\,\alpha'(t)=0$, where $k_i(t)$ is the principal curvature associated with the direction to which $\alpha$ is tangent. Then, N'(t) is everywhere parallel to $\alpha'(t)$ provided the $k_i(t)$ are constant, which is not the case in general.

Any idea regarding this proof of why the staments are not correct is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be false. What is correct is that $\alpha$ is never tangent to an asymptotic direction. The curve can certainly vary from a line of curvature without ever being tangent to an asymptotic direction. (The first condition is totally redundant.)

Comment: Do you mean that $K=-1$ is redundant, don't you? So... you say that given the conditions $\langle\alpha'(t),N(t)\rangle=0\quad\text{and}\quad\langle\alpha'(t),N'(t)\rangle\neq 0$ for all $t$, the curve is never tangent to an asymptotic direction. However, it is **not** true that the situation splits into two cases, namely, when $\alpha'$ and $N'$ are everywhere parallel, and when they are nowhere parallel, that is, according to the source, when $\alpha$ is everywhere or is never tangent to a principal direction.